# Escape reserved words in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

If the query string contains reserved words like `AND` or `OR`, how to escape those?

Example 1: `Brooklyn AND Bailey`

If I query the database it is searching for documents having `Brooklyn` and `Bailey` instead of string `Brooklyn AND Bailey`.

Example 2: `Brooklyn OR Bailey`

If I query the database it is searching for documents having either `Brooklyn` or `Bailey` instead of string `Brooklyn OR Bailey`.

This is my code.

```
esclient.search({
  from: 0,
  size: 5,
  body: {
    'query': {
      'query_string': {
        'query': 'title:' + term
      }
    }
  }
}).then(function(body) {
    // results
});
```

How to escape reserved words in query?

Comment: How would you know when to escape those reserved words or not? What if the user is really searching for both words using `AND`? What you could do is to lowercase the input so that `Brooklyn AND Bailey` becomes `brooklyn and bailey` and `and` is not a keyword anymore.

Comment: @Val Thanks for the info.